# Correctly move from a data member of a temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmove

Consider the following C++-Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct WrapMe
{
    WrapMe() { cout << "WrapMe Default Ctor of: " << this << endl; }
    WrapMe(const WrapMe& other) { cout << "WrapMe Copy Ctor of " << this << " from " << &other << endl; }
    WrapMe(WrapMe&& other) noexcept { cout << "WrapMe Move Ctor of " << this << " from " << &other << endl; }
    ~WrapMe() { cout << "Wrap Me Dtor of" << this << endl; }
};


struct Wrapper1
{
    WrapMe& data()& { return member; }
    WrapMe data()&& { return std::move(member); }

    WrapMe member;
};

struct Wrapper2
{
    WrapMe& data()& { return member; }
    WrapMe&& data()&& { return std::move(member); }

    WrapMe member;
};

int main()
{
    auto wrapMe1 = Wrapper1().data();
    auto wrapMe2 = Wrapper2().data();
}
```

with the output

```
WrapMe Default Ctor of: 00000092E7F2F8C4
WrapMe Move Ctor of 00000092E7F2F7C4 from 00000092E7F2F8C4
Wrap Me Dtor of00000092E7F2F8C4
WrapMe Default Ctor of: 00000092E7F2F8E4
WrapMe Move Ctor of 00000092E7F2F7E4 from 00000092E7F2F8E4
Wrap Me Dtor of00000092E7F2F8E4
[...]
```

Which is the correct way to move from the `WrapMe` member: Like `Wrapper1` (return by value) or like `Wrapper2` (return by rvalue-reference) does? Or are both ways equivalent here, as the ouput suggests? If not, why?

Comment: It makes a difference if the output of `data()` is passed to something that distinguishes between values and references. E.g. `void consume(WrapMe&&); consume(Wrapper1().data());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WrapMe&& data()&& { return std::move(member); }
```

This doesn't actually move anything. It just returns a rvalue reference to the member. For example I could do

```
auto&& wrapMe2 = Wrapper2().data();
```

and now `wrapMe2` will be a dangling reference or

```
auto w = wrapper2();
auto&& wrapMe2 = std::move(x).data();
```

Now I have a reference to the member of `w` without `w` having changed at all.

Only because the move constructor of `WrapMe` is called to initialize the `wrapMe2` object in the original line, a move operations actually takes place.

---

The version

```
WrapMe data()&& { return std::move(member); }
```

calls the move constructor already to construct the return value. The returned value will never refer to the original object or its member.

The line

```
auto wrapMe1 = Wrapper1().data();
```

then calls the move constructor again to initialize `wrapMe1` from the return value of `.data()`. The compiler is however allowed to elide this second move constructor call and instead construct `wrapMe1` directly from the expression in the return statement. This is why you see the same result.

With C++17 or later this elision would even be mandatory.

---

I don't know your use case, so I cannot be sure what the correct approach is, but just guessing on what you want to do:

For consistency between the two overloads, I would use the reference-returning version. Having `data` provide modifiable access to the member for lvalues, but not for rvalues, would be confusing.

However, you don't really need a member function to do this. Through `data` the caller has full control over the member anyway, so you could just make the member `public` from the start and then it could be used in the same way directly.

Comment: `and now wrapMe2 will be a dangling reference` Doesn't `Wrapper2.member` life extends until `wrapMe2` goes out of scope?

Comment: @rturrado I don't think so. The temporary is materialized by the member access `.`, not by being bound to a reference. Between the materialization and the reference binding only certain expressions are allowed for lifetime extension to still apply, calling a member function is not one of them, but accessing a data member would be, see https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6. So the usual lifetime rule until the end of the full expression should apply.

Comment: Great, many thanks for the explanation! I think I'll have to buy one of these Jason Turner's  Object Lifetime Puzzlers Books :)))